# fontFamily "FontAwesome" is not a system font - Expo error

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, font-awesome, native-base

I am trying to use some NativeBase components in my React Native app, however, when I try to load the fonts in App.js (as per to the NativeBase docs), I receive the following error;

**

> "fontFamily "FontAwesome" is not a system font and has not been loaded
> through Font.loadAsync."

**

My Code looks like;

```js
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';

import * as Font from 'expo-font';

import { AppLoading } from 'expo';
import Navigation from './src/navigation/Navigation.js';
import React from 'react';
import { Root } from 'native-base';

/**
 * Renders App.js
 * @return {*}
 */
export default class App extends React.Component {

  /**
   * Class constructor
   * @param {*} props
   */
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isReady: false,
    };
  }

  /**
   * Load fonts
   */
  async componentDidMount() {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      Roboto: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf'),
      Roboto_medium: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf'),
      FontAwesome: require('native-base/Fonts/FontAwesome.ttf'),
    });
    this.setState({ isReady: true });
  }

  /**
   * Render the component
   * @return {*}
   */
  render() {
    if (!this.state.isReady) {
      return <AppLoading />;
    }

    return (
      <Root>
        <Navigation />
      </Root>
    );
  }
}
```

I am quite baffled to why I am receiving the error, I seem to be loading in the FontAwesome.ttf correctly, and also its location is valid and found.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: It that the first font you are using? if so try to change it to 'Roboto' to see if it loading was also failed.

Comment: No luck, still getting the error. I realised the error appears as soon as I ran 'npm install expo-font', so it's not the code that's the problem at this point.